# HSQLDB / Oracle - more than 1000 items in IN clause

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, oracle11g, hsqldb

We have a lot of data in database and sometimes we need to call sql statements with more than 1000 items in IN clause. I know that those sql statements should be refactored and IN clause shouldn't have that much items but sometimes it's not that easy to keep an eye on each sql query. So I have a few questions.

1. What are the possibilities to solve this problem? I found few:

   - refactor sql statements - not always that easy
   - create temporary table for items so IN clause will look like this `... IN (SELECT id from temptable)` - might be a good idea
   - divide `IN` clause into few `IN` clauses like `... id IN (...) or id IN (...)`
2. Oracle db has limit for IN clause but I haven't found that limit for HSQLDB which we use for unit tests. Is it possible to set this limit through some configuration or some other way in HSQLDB?
3. Regarding temporary table for IN clause - how to create temporary table using HQL (we use Hibernate 4.2 in our application)? Is it possible?
4. Currently some `IN` clauses won't have more than 1000 items because we don't have that much data in db. But after application will be started on production (it is still in development process) there will be a lot of more data so we want to be ready for this.

What are your experiences with this problem. How have you solved it?

Details about our environment:

- Hibernate 4.2
- HSQLDB 2.3.2
- ORACLE 11g

Comment: Another good example why it is a bad idea to use a different DBMS for (unit) testing

Answer (score 2):

Re question 2, HSQLDB does not impose a limit on the number of items in the IN clause and no limit can be imposed.

Answer (score 0):

I think question 1 has been answered a lot already, but here's a link to an elegant solution from the [Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/235143).

Basically, you create a table type and a function that converts your comma separated string into a table.  That allows you to join to the returned table data.

Here's how we implemented for a comma separated list of numbers/IDs:

```
 create or replace function in_number_list (in_list in varchar2)  --send string
 return num_table                                      --return table of numbers
 as
 l_tab   num_table := num_table();           -- blank table
 l_text  varchar2(32767) := in_list || ',';  -- passed string + extra ','
 l_idx   number;                             -- a counter

 begin
 loop
   l_idx := instr(l_text, ',');              -- find the first comma position
   exit when nvl(l_idx,0) = 0;               -- if no more, break out of loop
   l_tab.extend;                             -- add a new row to table
   l_tab(l_tab.last) := to_number(trim(substr(l_text,1,l_idx-1)));
                                        -- add entry to table based on number
                                        -- split from string 
   l_text := substr(l_text,l_idx+1);         -- reset the original string
                                        -- trimming off what we've processed
 end loop;
 return l_tab;                               -- send back table of numbers
 end;
```